# Find common objects in multiple arrays by object ID

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched SO for a way to do this but most questions only support two arrays (I need a solution for multiple arrays).

I don't want to compare exact objects, I want to compare objects by their ID, as their other parameters may differ.

So here's the example data:

```
data1 = [{'id':'13','name':'sophie'},{'id':'22','name':'andrew'}, etc.]
data2 = [{'id':'22','name':'mary'},{'id':'85','name':'bill'}, etc.]
data3 = [{'id':'20','name':'steve'},{'id':'22','name':'john'}, etc.]
...
```

I'd like to return all objects whose ID appears in **all** arrays, and I don't mind *which* of the set of matched objects is returned.

So, from the data above, I'd expect to return any one of the following:

```
{'id':'22','name':'andrew'}
{'id':'22','name':'mary'}
{'id':'22','name':'john'}
```

Thanks

Comment: `data.find(el => el.id === '22')`

Comment: @Rayon what is `data`? If this is a solution can you please post it as a solution?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if `data` was an array of arrays, instead of a set of distinct variables

Comment: @Alnitak I can put all the arrays into an array called `data`, that's fine. But I still don't see what the number 22 has to do with my question :)

Comment: @Seano not me - that was someone else, who appears to have incorrectly assumed that you specifically want 22, and not which ever ID happens to be the one that's in every array.

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to be unique within each sub array ?

Comment: "*most questions only support two arrays*" - do you have an example question that nearly matches what you want - might be easier to adapt

Comment: @Alnitak don't worry, I know the confusion originated from Rayon but I actually meant to follow up with you

Comment: @Alnitak yes, the IDs are unique within each sub array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you really need an array of arrays - using a numeric suffix is not extensible:

```
let data = [ data1, data2, ... ];
```

Since you've confirmed that the IDs are unique within each sub array, you can simplify the problem by merging the arrays, and then finding out which elements occur `n` times, where `n` is the original number of sub arrays:

```
let flattened = data.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

let counts = flattened.reduce(
    (map, { id }) => map.set(id, (map.get(id) || 0) + 1), new Map()
);
```

and then you can pick out those objects that did appear `n` times, in this simple version they'll all come from the first sub array:

```
let found = data[0].filter(({ id }) => counts.get(id) === data.length);
```

Picking an arbitrary (unique) match from each sub array would be somewhat difficult, although picking just one row of `data` and picking the items from that would be relatively easy.  Either would satisfy the constraint from the question.

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` on the map line

Comment: this is ES6 code, that requires a modern browser.  I did also just fix a typo on the `.find` line

Comment: Can you make it into a snippet?

Comment: @Alnitak ok the code runs now but it only gives me the first match. I need it to find all matches.

Comment: @Seano you wrote: "I'd expect to return any _**one**_ of the following:"

Comment: ah, but there could be multiple IDs that each appear in every array?   Your test data didn't demonstrate that.

Comment: @Alnitak The full sentence in my question which you refer to is "I'd like to return all objects whose ID appears in all arrays, and I don't mind which of the set of matched objects is returned." - so you see I require all matches.

Comment: @Alnitak yes, here's your fiddle with the data updated - it should show both 13 and 22: https://jsfiddle.net/qy5ex8dg/1/

Comment: @Alnitak not sure what you mean by this "ah, but there could be multiple IDs that each appear in every array? Your test data didn't demonstrate that."

Comment: you didn't have the "13" appearing in all entries in the question

Comment: @Alnitak sorry but still not sure what you mean by the 13 comment? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: what I meant was that your sample data was insufficient to demonstrate that you want _one_ of _every_ value with the multiple IDs.   The only multiple ID in the question was 22.

Comment: in any event, I've updated my code to pick out all multiple ID values now, albeit it'll always pick the ones from data[0]

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want the unique object by Name

data1 = [{'id':'13','name':'sophie'},{'id':'22','name':'mary'}]
data2 = [{'id':'26','name':'mary'},{'id':'85','name':'bill'}]
data3 = [{'id':'29','name':'sophie'},{'id':'22','name':'john'}]


flattened = [ ...data1, ...data2, ...data3 ];

counts = flattened.reduce(
    (map, { name }) => map.set(name, (map.get(name) || 0) + 1), new Map()
);

names = []

found = flattened.filter(({ name }) => {
    if ((counts.get(name) > 1) && (!names.includes(name))) {
        names.push(name);
        return true
    }
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its too many loops but , if u can find the common id which is present in all the arrays then it would make your finding easier i think .you can have one array value as reference to find the common id

```
var global = [];
for(var i = 0;i<data1.length;i++){
var presence = true;
for(var j=0;j<arrays.length;j++){
    var temp = arrays[j].find(function(value){
        return data1[i].id == value.id;
    });
    if(!temp){
        presence = false;
        break;
    }
}
    if(presence){
       global.push(data1[i].id)
    }
}
console.log(global);
```

```js
var data1 = [{'id':'13','name':'sophie'},{'id':'22','name':'andrew'}];
var data2 = [{'id':'22','name':'mary'},{'id':'85','name':'bill'}];
var data3 = [{'id':'20','name':'steve'},{'id':'22','name':'john'}];
var arrays = [data1, data2, data3];
var global = [];
for(var i = 0;i<data1.length;i++){
    var presence = true;
 for(var j=0;j<arrays.length;j++){
  var temp = arrays[j].find(function(value){
   return data1[i].id == value.id;
  });
  if(!temp){
   presence = false;
            break;
  }
 }
if(presence){
 global.push(data1[i].id)
}
}
console.log(global);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's mention you you need *n* arrays, but also, given that you can:

> put all the arrays into an array called data

you can:

- combine your arrays
- get a list of duplicated IDs (via sort by ID)
- make that list unique (unique list of IDs)
- find entries in the combined list that match the unique IDs
- where the count of those items match the original number of arrays

Sample code:

```js
// Original data
var data1 = [{'id':'13','name':'sophie'},{'id':'22','name':'andrew'}]
var data2 = [{'id':'22','name':'mary'},{'id':'85','name':'bill'}]
var data3 = [{'id':'13','name':'steve'},{'id':'22','name':'john'}]

var arraycount = 3;

// Combine data into a single array

// This might be done by .pushing to an array of arrays and then using .length

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control
var data = [].concat(data1).concat(data2).concat(data3);
//console.log(data)

// Sort array by ID
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array
var sorted_arr = data.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
});
//console.log(sorted_arr)

// Find duplicate IDs
var duplicate_arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  if (sorted_arr[i + 1].id == sorted_arr[i].id) {
    duplicate_arr.push(sorted_arr[i].id);
  }
}

// Find unique IDs
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array
var unique = duplicate_arr.filter(function(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
//console.log(unique);

// Get values back from data
//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control
var matches = [];
for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; ++i) {
  var id = unique[i];
  matches.push(data.filter(function(e) {
    return e.id == id;
  }))
}
//console.log(matches)
// for data set this will be 13 and 22

// Where they match all the arrays
var result = matches.filter(function(value, index, self) {
  return value.length == arraycount;
})
//console.log("Result:")
console.log(result)
```

**Note:** *There's **very** likely to be more efficient methods.*.  I've left this in the hope part of it might help someone

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr1 = ["558", "s1", "10"]; 
var arr2 = ["55", "s1", "103"]; 
var arr3 = ["55", "s1", "104"]; 
var arr = [arr1, arr2, arr3]; 
   
console.log(arr.reduce((p, c) => p.filter(e => c.includes(e))));   
 
// output ["s1"]
```